# How to install half pieces when doing subway tiles

Tags: shower, tile, grout, ceramic-tile

When installing a subway tile layout in a shower, how does one install the half pieces that will occur on the ends?  Do you just cut the tile in half, flip it so the flat side is facing towards the corner (and not out) and hope that the grouting hides the flat side of all those pieces?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about inside corners, yes. You simply lap the two walls. Normally you'd put the grout line on the wall that is parallel to the most common viewing angle so it's less conspicuous. I tend to use slightly smaller grout lines in that situation to conceal them even more.

If you have any reason to believe you'll get movement at the corner, use caulk instead of grout there.

Comment: I'm talking about both.  I was assuming to have to caulk the corners (I mean, when will the walls really not shift, especially in a basement), but I was also wondering what to do on the sides as well.  i.e. if you were going from the corner to the door, every other row you'd have a half piece that you're going to have to cut.  What do you do in that situation?

Comment: Yeah, cut edges almost always go outward. You want grout lines between adjoining tiles to have factory edges.

Comment: Right, that's my dilema.  So when I'm tiling the side walls, when I get to the front (aka not the corner) I'm going to have half that are going to be complete [full size - 4 factory edges] and the other half are going to be half size, 3 factory edges.  Seems like my only options are to put the cut edge from the half piece to either be towards the opening or towards the corner.  Seems like I'm either going to have to grout against the cut side or have the cut size exposed, neither of which seem ideal.

Comment: you can ease over the edge  just a little with a tile sanding stone or file.

Comment: Do those work with a normal glazed tile or only solid stone tiles?  Seems like filing it would just expose the unfinished part of the tile